# Is this method of guaranteeing a fixed amount of random true values biased?

Tags: java, random

Assuming the `random()` function is random and returns a value in the range `[0, 1]`. Will the resulting `true` values be biased towards a direction in the array when using this method?

```
    int chances = 16;
    int guaranteed = 6;
    boolean[] result = new boolean[chances];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (random() <= (float) guaranteed / chances) {
            result[i] = true;
            guaranteed--;
        }
        chances--;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the code? Have it run 1000 times and see what the result is.

Comment: You are right. My bad. It appears to be random. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Unless you have a strong reason for using `float`, use `double`.

Comment: If you want exactly 6 out of 16, just create a `Collection` with those counts and [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force 6 `true` values out of 16, you must select 6 positions at random between 1 and 16. To do that you need to remove 6 indexes at random between 1 and 16 (or 0 and 15 for zero-based arrays)

Here is how to do that. The idea is to "remove" every selected index by sending it to the back of the array of indexes so it is not selected again.

1. `n := 16`
2. `indexes := (1, ..., 16)`
3. `boolean := (false, ..., false)` // 16 times
4. `6 times repeat:`

   ```
     i := integerRandom(1, n).
     ki := indexes[i].
     swap(indexes, n, ki).
     boolean[ki] := true.
     n := n - 1
   ```
5. `return boolean`